# MIni tube, Youtube app wont show any videos

Tags: 12.04, video, youtube

Does anyone use MiniTube for there Youtube videos ?

I downloaded this but it does not show any videos just descriptions where the video would be

[image: minitube]

Any ideas whats wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open your terminal do this

```
wget http://flavio.tordini.org/files/minitube/minitube-linux.tar.gz
```

Then

```
tar -xvf minitube-linux.tar.gz
      cd minitube/
      chmod +x minitube
     ./minitube
```

If you want to place it in desktop then do this also

```
ln minitube ~/Desktop
```

Then every time you can access it easily from desktop .

Answer (score 2):

You Tube made changes and that broke Minitube.  Minitube has been updated. [OMG! Ubuntu has the article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/09/desktop-youtube-app-minitube-adds-search-filtering-youtube-fix).